# ¿Cómo saber seleccionar elementos con tres o más repeticiones en una lista?

Tags: python, lista

estoy realizando un ejercicio el cuál es el siguiente:
Implementar en Python una función que recibe como parámetro una lista de números de cédulas de identidad de las personas que fueran vacunadas en un centro de vacunación COVID. Cada vez que aparece una cédula en esa lista, significa que se registró una dosis recibida por la persona (es decir, si en la lista una cédula x aparece 2 veces, significa que esa persona recibió dos dosis). La función debe construir un diccionario en el que, para cada cédula, almacene la cantidad de dosis recibidas y devolver una lista de los números de cédula que han recibido 3 o más dosis .

tengo un problema al momento de comparar, mi idea es realizar una lista la cuál tenga el elemento y las veces que aparece, y después convertirlo a diccionario.
el hecho es que se me ocurre comparar cada elemento en específico

```
 def dosiscedulas(lista):
    dicc={}
    vecescedula1=0
    vecescedula2=0
    vecescedula3=0
    for elem in lista:
        if elem==53655862:
            vecescedula1+=1
        else:
            if elem==4565678:
                vecescedula2+=1
            else:
                if elem==45568799:
                    vecescedula3+=1
    
    dicc={"53655862":vecescedula1,"4565678":vecescedula2,"45568799":vecescedula3}
    return dicc





print(dosiscedulas([53655862,53655862,4565678,45568799,53655862,4565678]))
```

existe alguna forma en la cuál no tenga que comparar cada cédula manualmente?, y en la cuál yo podría agregar otras cédulas que aparecieran más veces y me las contara automáticamente, ya que con esta solución si yo agrego una cédula nueva, tengo que crear otra variable, realizar devuelta la comparación, etc

Answer (score 2):

Python ya incorpora mucha funcionalidad para trabajar con colecciones de datos desde  el módulo `collections`, por ejemplo, puedes usar el objeto `Counter`, justamente para resolver tu inquietud. La entrada es una lista y la salida es un objeto `Counter` (básicamente una especialización de un diccionario):

```
from collections import Counter

dicc = Counter([53655862,53655862,4565678,45568799,53655862,4565678])
print(dicc)

Counter({53655862: 3, 4565678: 2, 45568799: 1})
```

Sobre esto podemos aplicar comprensión de listas para filtrar elementos que superen la cantidad deseada:

```
lista = [53655862,53655862,4565678,45568799,53655862,4565678]
dicc = {x: count for x, count in Counter(lista).items() if count >= 3}
print(dicc)

{53655862: 3}
```

Answer (score 2):

Python puro:

```
def dosiscedulas(lista):
    return list(set(x for x in lista if lista.count(x) > 2))
```

Es una expresión generadora que recorre elemento por elemento. Cada elemento es examinado con `if lista.count(x) > 2`. Esto cuenta las ocurrencias de `x` dentro de la lista. Si el número es mayor que 2, entonces `x` se incorpora a la comprensión.

La diferencia entre expresión generadora y comprensión de listas es que la última primero genera una lista y luego la entrega.

La expresión generadora va retornando de inmediato cada elemento, evitando construir la lista.

Con `set()` me aseguro de eliminar los duplicados y `list()` transforma de vuelta el *set* en una lista.

**Demo**

```
cel = [53655862,53655862,4565678,45568799,53655862,4565678,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6]

def dosiscedulas(lista):
    return list(set(x for x in lista if lista.count(x) > 2))

print(dosiscedulas(cel))
```

produce:

```
[5, 53655862, 6]


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Esa es la utilidad del diccionario: almacenar el contador por cada número de cédula, donde la cédula se convierte en la llave:

```
def dosiscedulas(lista):
    dicc={}
    for elem in lista:
        # insertar datos en el diccionario
        # si no existe la llave se crea con valor 1
        # si existe se incrementa su valor en 1
        dicc[elem] = dicc[elem] + 1 if dicc.get(elem, 0) else 1
    # retornar lista con las cédulas que tienen de tres dosis en adelante
    return [x for x in dicc.keys() if dicc[x] >= 3]


print(dosiscedulas([53655862,53655862,4565678,45568799,53655862,4565678]))
```

Comment: La expresión puede reducirse a `dicc[elem] = dicc.get(elem, 0) + 1`, no es necesario el `if/else`.